# SharePoint 2016 UserProfileApplicationProxy Proxy is null

Tags: user, 2016, service

I'm getting this error on my new 2016 farm  -

UserProfileApplicationProxy - Per Database User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization
UserProfileApplicationProxy Proxy is null. (Correlation=73eac29d-97ec-30fd-582d-bd574f7bab88)

This job only fails on 2 of my 4 web applications in the farm. Has anyone seen this error before?
Thank you.

Comment: How did you fixed this ?? I am also facing same issue in 2016.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies, I have now sorted this. The User Profile Service Application Proxy was not associated with the web application.

Comment: Saved me from headache. :)